# invalid argument running docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker, trying to run docker image locally according to instruction [here](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow)

I pull the image by `docker pull puckel/docker-airflow`, then prepare the `.yml` file and `run docker-compose up -d` but keep showing the error:

```
Error response from daemon: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2/: invalid argument
```

Not sure which part is missing here.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there are some corrupted images, try to remove all cache and containers and pull them again.

```
docker system prune --all
docker volume prune 
docker-compose -f docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml up -d
```

Answer (score 10):

Check your .env file. There will be some invalid syntax.

Answer (score 5):

My problem the `.env` file.

I found that in my .env file I had written some variable names, but did not assign any values. Example of my .env file

```
# The wrong .env file content
VAR1=A 
VAR2=B 
VAR3
```

VAR3 would then be the problem, it should have been at least

```
# The correct .env file
VAR1=A 
VAR2=B 
VAR3=
```

Remark the `=` sign at `VAR3`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it has been same as @Jakob suggested.
I have defined the env variable but hasn't provided any value.

Before:

```
S3_BUCKET
```

After:

```
S3_BUCKET=''
```

After above change, it worked for me.